# Symfony2 change log directory outside app (rootDir)

Tags: symfony

Here is my code, from symfony book.

```
public function getCacheDir() {
    return $this->rootDir . '/access-logs/' . $this->environment . '/cache/';
}

public function getLogDir() {
    return $this->rootDir . '/access-logs/' . $this->environment . '/logs/';
}
```

Now the directory is at **PROJECTNAME/app/access-logs**/dev/cache

But i need at **PROJECTNAME/access-logs**/dev/cache

**NOTE : "I need outside app directory and inside project directory"**

Comment: why `/../` not working?

Comment: Without adding the above code **i.e default symfony2 structure, work fine**. But, after adding the above code also `/../` , **creates error** in log as : [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                                                             
  Cannot rename '/xx/xx/xx' to '/xx/xx/xx/_old'.
Permission is 777 for /access-logs/ (chmod 777 -R). Given multiple times, same error.

Comment: Instead of giving above code. Is there any config methods in yml file? Symfony2 setting or config.

Comment: No, this is the only way to configure this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from symfony3

```
public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}
```

Now the location is **PROJECT_DIR/var/** just change **var/cache** to **access-logs**

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are editing this is AppKernel.php? Try this:

```
public function getCacheDir() {
    return dirname(__DIR__) . '/access-logs/' . $this->environment . '/cache/';
}

public function getLogDir() {
    return dirname(__DIR__) . '/access-logs/' . $this->environment . '/logs/';
}
```

dirname(__DIR__) returns the path to the PROJECTNAME dir.